# How could I filter and sort array of hashes according to another array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I want to filter and sort an array of hashes:

```
[
  {"_id"=>"THAILAND", "cities"=>["BANGKOK", "CHIANGMAI"]},
  {"_id"=>"MALAYSIA", "cities"=>["JAKARTA", "KUALA_LUMPUR"]},
  {"_id"=>"JAPAN", "cities"=>["HOKKAIDO", "FUKUOKA", "TOKYO", "IBARAKI", "ISHIGAKI", "OSAKA", "KUMAMOTO", "KAGOSHIMA", "NAGOYA", "OKINAWA"]},
  {"_id"=>"HONGKONG", "cities"=>["HONGKONG"]},
  {"_id"=>"KOREA", "cities"=>["SEOUL", "BUSAN"]},
  {"_id"=>"TAIWAN", "cities"=>["KAOHSIUNG", "TAIPEI"]},
  {"_id"=>"AUSTRALIA", "cities"=>["MELBOURNE", "GOLD_COAST", "PERTH", "SYDNEY"]},
  {"_id"=>"MACAU", "cities"=>["MACAU"]},
  {"_id"=>"SINGAPORE", "cities"=>["SINGAPORE"]}
]
```

according to the array:

```
["JAPAN", "THAILAND", "KOREA", "TAIWAN", "AUSTRALIA", "MACAU", "SINGAPORE"]
```

The expected result is:

```
[
  {"_id"=>"JAPAN", "cities"=>["HOKKAIDO", "FUKUOKA", "TOKYO", "IBARAKI", "ISHIGAKI", "OSAKA", "KUMAMOTO", "KAGOSHIMA", "NAGOYA", "OKINAWA"]},
  {"_id"=>"THAILAND", "cities"=>["BANGKOK", "CHIANGMAI"]},
  {"_id"=>"KOREA", "cities"=>["SEOUL", "BUSAN"]},
  {"_id"=>"TAIWAN", "cities"=>["KAOHSIUNG", "TAIPEI"]},
  {"_id"=>"AUSTRALIA", "cities"=>["MELBOURNE", "GOLD_COAST", "PERTH", "SYDNEY"]},
  {"_id"=>"MACAU", "cities"=>["MACAU"]},
  {"_id"=>"SINGAPORE", "cities"=>["SINGAPORE"]}
]
```

How could I do that in an elegant way?

This is how I plan to implement it.

## I think my idea looks so messy and not easy to understand

```
    candidates = [
          {"_id"=>"THAILAND", "cities"=>["BANGKOK", "CHIANGMAI"]},
          {"_id"=>"MALAYSIA", "cities"=>["JAKARTA", "KUALA_LUMPUR"]},
          {"_id"=>"JAPAN", "cities"=>["HOKKAIDO", "FUKUOKA", "TOKYO", "IBARAKI", "ISHIGAKI", "OSAKA", "KUMAMOTO", "KAGOSHIMA", "NAGOYA", "OKINAWA"]},
          {"_id"=>"HONGKONG", "cities"=>["HONGKONG"]},
          {"_id"=>"KOREA", "cities"=>["SEOUL", "BUSAN"]},
          {"_id"=>"TAIWAN", "cities"=>["KAOHSIUNG", "TAIPEI"]},
          {"_id"=>"AUSTRALIA", "cities"=>["MELBOURNE", "GOLD_COAST", "PERTH", "SYDNEY"]},
          {"_id"=>"MACAU", "cities"=>["MACAU"]},
          {"_id"=>"SINGAPORE", "cities"=>["SINGAPORE"]}
        ]

    a = ["JAPAN", "THAILAND", "KOREA", "TAIWAN", "AUSTRALIA", "MACAU", "SINGAPORE"]

    a.inject([]) { h, country
        tmp_candidate = {}
        candidates.each do |candidate|
            if country == candidate['_id']
                tmp_candidate = candidate
                break
            end
        end
        h << tmp_candidate
        h
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO isn't a "give me code" site, it's a site where we help fix the code you've written. We expect to see an example of your effort. Read "[ask]" and the links at the bottom of that page.

Comment: In future, please pare down your examples to the bare minimum that still make the point. Here, for example, three countries and at most two cities per country would have been sufficient. It is also helpful to assign a variable to each of the example's inputs (e.g., `arr = [ { "_id"=>...},...]` and `countries=[" JAPAN",...]`). That way , readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
a = ["JAPAN", "THAILAND", "KOREA", "TAIWAN", "AUSTRALIA", "MACAU", "SINGAPORE"]

[{"_id"=>"THAILAND", "cities"=>["BANGKOK", "CHIANGMAI"]},
 {"_id"=>"MALAYSIA", "cities"=>["JAKARTA", "KUALA_LUMPUR"]},
 {"_id"=>"JAPAN", "cities"=>["HOKKAIDO", "FUKUOKA", "TOKYO", "IBARAKI", "ISHIGAKI", "OSAKA", "KUMAMOTO", "KAGOSHIMA", "NAGOYA", "OKINAWA"]},
 {"_id"=>"HONGKONG", "cities"=>["HONGKONG"]},
 {"_id"=>"KOREA", "cities"=>["SEOUL", "BUSAN"]},
 {"_id"=>"TAIWAN", "cities"=>["KAOHSIUNG", "TAIPEI"]},
 {"_id"=>"AUSTRALIA", "cities"=>["MELBOURNE", "GOLD_COAST", "PERTH", "SYDNEY"]},
 {"_id"=>"MACAU", "cities"=>["MACAU"]},
 {"_id"=>"SINGAPORE", "cities"=>["SINGAPORE"]}]
.select{|h| a.index(h["_id"])}
.sort_by{|h| a.index(h["_id"])}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your first array is `arr` and your second is `countries`,

```
arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|  h.update(g["_id"]=>g) }.
    values_at(*countries).
    compact
  #=> [{"_id"=>"JAPAN",     "cities"=>[...]},
  #    {"_id"=>"THAILAND",  "cities"=>[...]},
  #    {"_id"=>"KOREA",     "cities"=>[...]},
  #    {"_id"=>"TAIWAN",    "cities"=>[...]},
  #    {"_id"=>"AUSTRALIA", "cities"=>[...]},
  #    {"_id"=>"MACAU",     "cities"=>[...]},
  #    {"_id"=>"SINGAPORE", "cities"=>[...]}]
```

`.compact` is needed only if one or more of the elements in `countries` may not have a corresponding hash in `arr`.